# re.match is returning true on two different strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using `re.match` function of python to compare two strings by ignoring few characters like this:

```
import re

url = "/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp/xyz"

if re.match( '/ChessBoard_x.._y..\.bmp', url ):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

**Problem#1:** the **output is true** but I want false here because the url has something extra after **.bmp** **Problem#2:** I have used **two dots** here to ignore the value 16 (`x16 & y16`) but in fact this value can contain any number of digits like `x8, x16, x256` etc. So what should I do to ignore this complete value consisting of any number of digits?

Answer (score 3):

Try the regex

```
'/ChessBoard_x[\d]+_y[\d]+\.bmp$'
```

A small demo (Also try on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yN8iE6/1))

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile('/ChessBoard_x[\d]+_y[\d]+\.bmp$')
>>> url = "/ChessBoard_x162_y162.bmp"
>>> pat.match(url).group()
'/ChessBoard_x162_y162.bmp'
>>> url = "/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp/xyz"
>>> pat.match(url).group() 
>>> # Does not match
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: You need to specify that you want the string to terminate at the end of the regex. The $ operator does that:

```
re.match("/ChessBoard_x.._y..\.bmp$", url)
```

Problem 2: What you want is one or more digits. The \d character class matches digits, + will match one or more of them. I replace the two dots with \d+ therefore:

```
re.match("/ChessBoard_x\d+_y\d+\.bmp$", url)
```